# Add values to loop in corresponding order

Tags: python, loops, instance-variables

Hey so I want to add the information that is retrieved from my parser in this case the InfoLoop() to a variable with all the attributes.

```
    movie_list = jp_movies, maxx
    # these values in movie_list include tokens ei(107290) that the parser takes and 
    # it then grabs all the key info I want about that movie with Imdbpy plugin


    print("Processing...")
    # print the title for the shows found with token
    for movie_list in movie_list:
        returnlist = Media.InfoLoop(movie_list)
        print ("Info found for: "+ returnlist.show_title())
```

This works and returns the info I want:

> Info found for: Jurassic Park
>
> Info found for: Mad Max: Fury Road

Since the returnlist includes the information I want I then want to pass it back to another class instance that is asking for this information in order.

```
     # Share with Movie()
     print("Pushing values to instance...")
     for movie_list in movie_list:
         Media.Movie((returnlist.show_title()),
                     max_test,
                     (returnlist.show_cover()),
                     max_max_youtube,
                     (returnlist.show_year()),
                     (returnlist.show_rating()))
```

Now the code above outputs the correct values as well. I want it to loop these actions for every movie.

Is there a way to have it store the info from Media.Movie into the variables inside movie_list (jp_movie, maxx) ie the movie it gets the list for.

**Updated and currently working with:**

```
    jp_movies, maxx = str(107290), str(1392190)
    movie_list = [jp_movies, maxx]

    for movie in movie_list:
    print("Processing...")
    returnlist = Media.InfoLoop(movie_list)
    print ("Info found for: "+ returnlist.show_title())
    print("Pushing values to instance...")
    current_movie = Media.Movie((returnlist.show_title()),
                                max_test,
                                (returnlist.show_cover()),
                                mad_max_youtube,
                                (returnlist.show_year()),
                                (returnlist.show_rating()))
    movie_list.append(current_movie)
```

it throws a `'str' object has no attribute 'append'`

Pretty new to python so please be nice :3!

Comment: `for movie_list in movie_list` is, at best, needlessly confusing.

Comment: Sorry yah it seemed to work so i kept it lol. I basically want it to loop for the number of values in movie_list is there a better way to do that? @ScottHunter

Answer (score 0):

So I understand you want to keep the info for all the movies, correct?
For that, you will need to store each movie's data in a different place; The recommended way is to use a list. right now you are rewriting the same object, which is why it only saves the last movie.
Also, you used the name "movie_list" twice: once for the list and another for the object in the for loop.
You should try the following:

```
print("Pushing values to instance...")
my_movie_list = []
for movie in movie_list:
    returnlist = Media.InfoLoop(movie)
    current_movie = Media.Movie((returnlist.show_title()),
                max_test,
                (returnlist.show_cover()),
                max_max_youtube,
                (returnlist.show_year()),
                (returnlist.show_rating()))
    my_movie_list.append(current_movie)
```

Let me know if this works

Comment: Hey! Doesn't throw any errors but I have some questions. 1. what does it get stored as in the my_movie_list? 2. What is .append doing in this situation?

Comment: Ill try my best

Comment: oh I am guessing I should add those variables (jp_movie and maxx) inside my_movie_list correct?

Comment: What type are jp_movies and maxx? what each of them represents?

Comment: They are the original tokens that are passed to the parser to look up the movie info. They are declared like: `jp_movies, maxx = str(107290), str(1392190)`